# Is there a git config for not pushing tags by default

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-tag

I'd like to prevent my team members from pushing their tags on to the git repo. Essentially, some tags got added unintentionally, now they can't be removed unless I coordinate with everyone's private repository simultaneously. They keep getting re-pushed.

I can have everyone change their configuration to not push tags.

Is there a setting? What other ideas would achieve the goal? Server-side hooks?

Comment: Yes, you could create a hook that rejects pushed tags unless they are e.g. authored by user XY. I think that would be the best solution here if you really want to enforce this.

Comment: Hooks aren't my first choice since we are using bitbucket and the server-side hooks are limited.

Comment: "I can have everyone change their configuration to not push tags." I'm not clear on how coordinating a client config change with all of your developers is any easier than coordinating a client-side tag cleanup, but by default `git push` _doesn't_ push tags. You have to specify them directly or use an option like `--tags`.

Comment: most of the team is using SourceTree or Visual Studio 2015.